# Quick switching between hhvm and zend php

Tags: php, hhvm

Is there any simple/comfortable/fast way of switching between default `php` interpreter and `hhvm`?

Having project in PHP 5.2, I'd like to work on it on `hhvm` locally and switch to `php` before commiting to see if everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your php code using nginx+fpm (or apache+fpm) as FastCGI, HHVM comes as drop in replacement of fpm as it has fastCGI support. You can start with the migration and post the issues at official page of hhvm. (https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues)